# SSIS Connection is not working with Amazon Redshift after export the project from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, amazon-redshift

I had built a SSIS package which were truncating some tables in Amazon Redshift. I need to have some enhancement, so I have exported the project from SSIS and trying to edit the package. Now old connection is not working and neither it is giving any specific error.  I am trying to use same user and password.

Below is the error:

[image]

Though it is saying about configuration, but the same configuration is fine in production. And I am in the server box.

Comment: By "exported the project from SSIS" do you mean you exported it from the SSIS catalog? This process has probably lost the password. Did you re enter it? Have you tested the connection manager in SSDT? Interactive runs in SSDT (that is shown in your screenshot) don't use configurations, whereas published packages can use configurations, so that's another reason that the published package would work and an exported one wouldn't

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have imported it from .ispac file. And when I am checking the connection, it is all right. Connection test succeeded. But the next moment, when I am firing the sql task it is giving the error.

Comment: Are there any expressions on the connection overriding it's values? (are there any little fx signs on it?)

Comment: Yes.. This is a ado.net connection and all the connection string is passed by variables

Comment: And the variables have the correct connection string? Are they in turn populated from parameters?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Yes.. All the variables are from project parameters.. :) and they are being concatenated in a expression to make a connection string

Comment: Normally there is a more specific error in the output. But it depends on what Redshift supplies. Since you can test the connection OK, it must be being overwritten by a parameter or expression at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

McDermaid.. Thanks a lot for your active support and help.. I have found the solution.

The issue was related to 32 and 64 bit debug mode.. When I convert to 32 bit and rebuilt it worked properly. Sorry to reply late.. But, this is how it was solved.

Again thanks for your help